# Getting error invalid number in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM coa_cook 
WHERE grt_tOOK_ID IN (301173, 301202)
```

and  `grt_tOOK_ID` is of `varchar2` data type in the table.

I am getting this error :

> ORA-01722: invalid number

Someone has told me to put quotes between them as it is `varchar2` data type please advise

Answer (score 4):

The column is a varchar (not a number). You could use

```
SELECT * FROM coa_cook WHERE grt_tOOK_ID IN ('301173','301202')
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM coa_cook WHERE TO_NUMBER(grt_tOOK_ID) IN (301173,301202)
```